# CoreBluetooth shows devices/peripherals with Bluetooth turned off

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

```
var peripherals = [CBPeripheral]()

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if let _ = peripheral.name {
        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
            table.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Using the delegate method above, called after `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)`, I am showing available peripherals(only those with `name`).

Since some of the available devices are also mine, I am sure that bluetooth is turned off on them.
So why does this method returns them as available? Are they cached somewhere or?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "Bluetooth off". Have you turned off the Bluetooth switch in settings or just turned off the Bluetooth icon in control center (where you swipe down). For this second case you have turned off Bluetooth discoverability but Bluetooth is still on. Your own devices will be connected so that things like cut/paste sharing etc still work.

Comment: I have turned it off in control centre, so it should not be discoverable. Tried with few devices but they are always found as peripherals.

Comment: You need to turn it off in settings, not just in control Center.